# Different calculation of median and quartiles, bug in BoxWhiskerChart?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, plotting

When you plot a dataset with `BoxWhiskerChart` passing over the box in the plot with your mouse pointer shows some specifics about the dataset (min and max values, 1/4, 1/2, and 3/4 quartiles).
However, if you use `Quartiles` or `Median` to calculate those values, they do not correspond. The values displayed by `BoxWhiskerChart` are different. Does anyone have an explanation or is it simply a bug? Is it system specific (here 8.0.1 on OSX 10.6.8)?

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 20]
BoxWhiskerChart[data]
Quartiles[data]
Median[data]
```

Comment: What happens if you try with an odd number of elements? If I remember well, the `Median[]`definition changes for lists of odd and even lengths.

Comment: @belisarius Good point. With an odd number of elements the median is correct, however, the 1/4 and 3/4 quartiles are still wrong.

Comment: @VLC: that would be "different", not "wrong". *Mathematica* allows for different parameters for `Quantile[]`, as I have indicated in my answer.

Comment: @J.M. you're right (or "different"). I wrote my comment just a sec before your answer appeared.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What `BoxWhiskerChart[]` is actually using for the quartiles (and the median as well) is `Quantile[data, {1/4, 1/2, 3/4}]`, or more explicitly, `Quantile[data, {1/4, 1/2, 3/4}, {{0, 0}, {1, 0}}]` (what the docs calls the "inverse empirical CDF" parameters).

`Quartiles[data]` (and thus also `Median[]`), on the other hand, is equivalent to `Quantile[data, {1/4, 1/2, 3/4}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}]` ("linear interpolation" parameters); these two different ways to specify the quantiles will almost always give different results for a particular data set.

<strike>Unfortunately, there does not seem to be an easy way to let `BoxWhiskerChart[]` know what parameters you prefer to use for `Quantile[]`.</strike>

Brett's answer displays the (not-too-well documented) `"BoxRange"` suboption for `Method`; as I mentioned in a comment, the compact way to use that along with whatever quantile definition you prefer is `BoxWhiskerChart[data, Method -> {"BoxRange" -> (Quantile[#, Range[0, 1, 1/4], {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] &)}]`, and you can replace `{{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}` with your desired parameter set.

Comment: With the `LabelingFunction` Option you could at least show the desired values in the tooltip box

Answer (score 14):

There's an `Method` option, `"BoxRange"` that can be used to control the calculation of the box parameters:

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, GridLines -> {None, Quartiles[data]},
   Method -> {"BoxRange" -> (Flatten[{Min[#], Quartiles[#], Max[#]}] &)}]
```

[image: box-whisker chart]

The first example under **Properties & Relations** that shows how the various properties of the chart are calculated, using a concrete dataset.

Comment: `Method -> {"BoxRange" -> (Quantile[#, Range[0, 1, 1/4], {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] &)}` is a bit more compact...

Comment: @brett-champion, Do you know what is happening to the "Outliers" when you change the "BoxRange" method?  See [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/108212/9490) to see, some outliers are being removed when we use a custom box range.

Answer (score 4):

By using J. M.'s answer, this will provide you with a "corrected" tooltip:

```
label[data_, index_, label_] := 
  Grid[{{Style["max", Bold], 1},           {Style["75%", Bold], #1[[2]]}, 
        {Style["median", Bold], #1[[3]]},  {Style["25%", Bold], #1[[4]]}, 
        {Style["min", Bold], #1[[5]]}}, 
     Dividers -> {{#, #}, {#, #}} &@{Directive[GrayLevel[0.3]], Directive[GrayLevel[0.3]]}, 
     Alignment -> {{Center, ".", {Left}}}, Frame -> GrayLevel[0], 
     BaseStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Dashing[{}]]] &@
   Join[{Max@data}, Reverse@Quartiles[data], {Min@data}];

data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 20]; 

BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[label[##], Tooltip] &), 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[Range[2005, 2009], None]]
```

[image: box-whisker chart with modified tooltips]

Comment: I'd replace `Join[{Max@data}, Reverse@Quartiles[data], {Min@data}]` with `Quantile[data, Range[1, 0, -1/4], {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}]` myself...