# The default bandwidth of the SmoothKernelDistribution function

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, implementation-details

I am researching the Silverman rule of thumb for bandwidth selection.
Below is a sample of my code, from which it seems that BW=63 is close to the default parameter given by *Mathematica* (2 images are quite similar).

```
data4 = RandomReal[1024, {3600, 2}];
\[ScriptCapitalD]1 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data4];
\[ScriptCapitalD]2 = SmoothKernelDistribution[data4, 63];
{ContourPlot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]1, {x, y}], {x, 0, 1024}, {y, 0, 1024}], 
 ContourPlot[PDF[\[ScriptCapitalD]2, {x, y}], {x, 0, 1024}, {y, 0, 1024}]}
```

[image: 2 images are similar]

Yet, according to articles the definition for Silverman R.O.T. should be:

```
H1 = (4/(dim + 2))^(1/(dim + 4))*n^(-1/(dim + 4)) StandardDeviation[data4[[All, 1]]]
(* -> 74.7864 *)
```

When I did this analysis for the 1D case, the *Mathematica* results fit well to expectations.

My question is: How does *Mathematica* calculate BW by default? How can I see the BW results (other than trial and error until images are alike)?

Comment: Bill thank you. i probably missed explain my self. The default Mathematica "Silverman" is diffrent from the literature "Silverman". my question is how doeas mathematica calculates Silverman R.O.T?

Comment: I figured that out once I realized Silverman was the default. What are you using for dim and n in your example?

Comment: n=3600 and dim=2

Comment: When I use those numbers, I get h1=293 or so for the data4 in your post.

Comment: H1 = n^(-1/(dim + 4)) StandardDeviation[Data[[All, 1]]] sorry for the mistake. Still it is qiute far from the expected Silverman BW=63

Comment: is it possible you have dim and n reversed?

Comment: fro reference w you can look at http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/718/NonParametrics1.pdf  page 17. in this case q=2 is the dimension and nu=2 as well

Comment: Dear Doron: good question. I edited your post to bring the the formatting and layout up to site standards. Although the original was quite acceptable in the abstract, please take note of my changes so that you'll know for the future how questions and answers should be presented (e.g., we do not write a heading for the post or use salutations).

Comment: The documentation gives their particular version of the Silverman rule within the documentation for `KernelMixtureDistribution[]`.

Answer (score 11):

I'd like to add to my previous comment that the undocumented "Bandwidth" property exists for `SmoothKernelDistribution` (SKD) and `KernelMixtureDistribution` (KMD).

Note that in the multivariate case there is a bit of inconsistency in how this is currently handled for SKD vs. KMD. SKD simplifies the bandwidth matrix when the off-diagonal elements are zeros.  KMD gives the full bandwidth matrix.  Note that the `KernelMixtureDistribution` docs give a good bit of detail on what this all means.

```
data4 = RandomReal[1024, {3600, 2}];

SmoothKernelDistribution[data4]["Bandwidth"]

(*{64.2393, 64.7462}*)

KernelMixtureDistribution[data4]["Bandwidth"]

(*{{64.2393, 0.}, {0., 64.7462}}*)
```

Now as for how things are computed. I always recommend using `KernelMixtureDistribution` with `MaxMixtureKernels` set to `All` this gives the precise definition of a kernel density estimator and can act on symbolic data. This will be very handy for you in determining how things are computed.  For example:

```
FullSimplify[#["Bandwidth"], DistributionParameterAssumptions[#]] &
    [KernelMixtureDistribution[Array[x, 4], "Silverman", MaxMixtureKernels -> All]]

(*(1/(20 2^(
 2/5)))3 √(9 x[1]^2 + 9 x[2]^2 + 9 x[3]^2 - 6 x[3] x[4] + 
    9 x[4]^2 - 6 x[2] (x[3] + x[4]) - 6 x[1] (x[2] + x[3] + x[4]))*)
```

Note that `SmoothKernelDistribution` is effectively a linear interpolation of the PDF for `KernelMixtureDistribution` so all of the properties like bandwidth are the same.

**EDIT:**

I'd like to add two things. First, there is some confusion that has arisen because there are in fact two rules of thumb attributed to Silverman that differ by a constant (0.9 vs about 1.06).  *Mathematica* uses a constant 0.9 for the default `"Silverman"` method. This is mainly because 1.06 assumes the underlying distribution is normal. For distributions with heavier tails or multiple modes Silverman claims that 1.06 will oversmooth and suggests 0.9 is a better choice. See [B. W. Silverman, *"Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis"*, Chapman & Hall/CRC, 1986, pages 45–48](http://books.google.com/books?id=e-xsrjsL7WkC&pg=PA45) for details.

Since there is no prior knowledge on what the underlying distribution might be the more robust 0.9 constant was chosen as default.

To use the alternate Silverman rule of thumb (using the optimal constant for an underlying normal distribution) use `"StandardGaussian"`.

Note that for the Buffalo snowfall data `"StandardGaussian"` achieves precicely the same value computed by wolfies.

```
KernelMixtureDistribution[
   ExampleData[{"Statistics", "BuffaloSnow"}], "StandardGaussian"]["Bandwidth"]

(* 10.9706 *)
```

Second, for higher dimensions the Silverman rule is given similar to what the OP posts but with an additional constant $\displaystyle\frac{9 \times 3^{1/5}}{10\times 2^{2/5}}$. The following function should give the same result as the `"Silverman"` method for any dimension.

```
bwSilverman[data_] := Block[{dim, n, c0, c1, c2, sd, iqr},
  dim = If[MatrixQ[data], Length[First[data]], 1];
  n = Length[data];
  c0 = (9 3^(1/5))/(10 2^(2/5));
  c1 = (4/(dim + 2))^(1/(dim + 4));
  c2 = n^(-1/(dim + 4));
  sd = StandardDeviation[data];
  iqr = (Quantile[data, .75] - Quantile[data, .25])/1.34;

  If[dim == 1,
   c0 c1 c2 Min[sd, iqr],
   MapThread[c0 c1 c2 Min[#1, #2] &, {sd, iqr}]
   ]

  ]

  bwSilverman[data4]

  (*{64.2393, 64.7462}*)
```

Comment: As an addition to Andy's notes, you can use `"Properties"` to list all the possible properties of a `DataDistribution[]` object.

Comment: Andy wrote: `Silverman ... differ by a constant (0.9 vs about 1.06).`  Well, in the 1.06 version ... the 1.06 is _not_ a constant ... it only happens to be 1.06 in the case of a Gaussian kernel. For any other kernel, the 1.06 changes depending on the kernel being used. Are you saying that _Mathematica_ uses a constant 0.9 * blah for ALL kernels, when Silverman method is selected? Surely not?

Comment: @wolfies it differs by kernel function and is hard coded for each. For user defined kernels there is a fixed constant .9. It is obviously possible to derive the optimal value if the underlying distribution is known but this seemed like more work than it was worth at the time. If it is critical functionality I recommend filing a suggestion with WRI.

Comment: @AndyRoss I'm not convinced that is actually Silverman's rule-of-thumb then. I don't have time right now, but will try have a look at all this later in the week.   ..... May I ask: Why do you have `SmoothKernelDistribution` and `KernelMixtureDistribution`?  I can see that `SmoothKernelDistribution` uses linear interpolation (so it's just approximate) ... Is `KernelMixtureDistribution` meant to be exact?

Comment: @wolfies `KernelMixtureDistribution` is meant to be exact if `MaxMixtureKernels` is set to `All`.

Comment: @Andy, since I don't have Silverman's book handy: did he also explain in his book the reason for the additional factor for multivariate data?

Comment: @J.M. not really.  It seems to have been an observation from experience rather than a mathematical derivation.  We should all keep in mind that bandwidth selection is much more of an art than a science and few are better smoothing "artists" than Silverman.

Answer (score 5):

The original poster ponders why, in a bivariate model, the `SmoothKernelDistribution` function ... using the Silverman 'rule of thumb' estimate of bandwidth ... yields results that do not match the original poster's calculations.

I had the same issue in a univariate form.

**Short version**
It turns out that there are two versions of the Silverman rule of thumb in common usage, at least in the univariate case.

**Long version**
Here is Parzen's (1979) yearly 'Snowfall in Buffalo' data (63 data points collected from 1910 to 1972, and measured in inches):

```
data = ExampleData[{"Statistics", "BuffaloSnow"}];
```

According to the help file for `SmoothKernelDistribution`, *Mathematica* states that, by default:

- For bandwidth selection: 'By default the "Silverman" method is used'
- The Gaussian kernel is used; *i.e.*,  $$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right),\qquad -\infty<x<\infty$$

  ```
  gauss = Exp[-(x^2/2)]/Sqrt[2 Pi];
  domain[gauss] = {x, -Infinity, Infinity};
  ```

Under these assumptions, (see, for instance, even the [simple wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation)), the Silverman rule of thumb method reduces to:

```
((4*StandardDeviation[data]^5)/(3*Length[data]))^(1/5)
```

> 10.9706

This is exactly the same result we get with the `Bandwidth` function in the mathStatica add-on to *Mathematica*, specifying the Silverman method and a Gaussian kernel:

```
Bandwidth[data, gauss, Method -> Silverman]
```

> 10.9706

[ It is worth noting here that the mathStatica answer is not a pre-prepared/caged answer for the Gaussian case ... rather, as part of its general design, mathStatica calculates from scratch the bandwidth that minimises asymptotic mean integrated square error, according to Silverman's rule of thumb, using the user's specified kernel. ]

*Mathematica* 9 returns something different:

```
SmoothKernelDistribution[data]["Bandwidth"]
```

> 9.32148

Changing from a Gaussian kernel to another kernel doesn't seem to help resolve the discrepancy.

---

So what is *Mathematica* doing? In the Gaussian case, the theoretical Silverman rule of thumb calculation is (for our data set with 63 observations):

```
2*(1/24)^(1/5) * 
Min[StandardDeviation[data],
    (Quantile[data, .75] - Quantile[data, .25])/1.34] n^(-1/5) /. n -> 63
```

> 10.9706

where:

```
kk = 2*(1/24)^(1/5) // N
```

> 1.05922

If one does a quick web search, you can find this constant multiplier 1.05922 given in dozens of papers on Silverman's rule-of-thumb for the Gaussian case.

By contrast, *Mathematica* seems to use this result (with 0.9 instead of 1.05922 etc) ... [ kindly confirmed by J.M. - see comment below ]

```
0.9 *
Min[StandardDeviation[data],
    (Quantile[data, .75] - Quantile[data, .25])/1.34] n^(-1/5) /. n -> 63
```

> 9.32148

which is, according to [this CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6670), the formula given in the STATA user manual entry for the STATA function `kdensity`. It's a very blunt kind of 0.9; not 0.91121212... , just 0.9.

### **Update**

Based on [the R manual](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/bandwidth.html), it seems there are, in fact, two versions of Silverman's rule of thumb in implementation ... an approximate value 0.9  ...  and the actual theoretical value 1.05922 .... just to keep everyone on their toes :)

There is a very nice theoretical derivation of the exact Silverman 1.05922 ROT result [here](http://www.ssc.wisc.edu/~bhansen/718/NonParametrics1.pdf) (see page 11 and top page 12), by Hansen. I still don't know the theoretical basis for the 0.9 usage?? ... will do some library hunting.

Comment: The version of Silverman's rule used, as I mentioned in the comments, is in the docs for `KernelMixtureDistribution[]`: `silvermanBandwidth[data_] := Module[{n = Length[data], iqr = Quantile[data, .75] - Quantile[data, .25], sd = StandardDeviation[data]}, .9 Min[iqr/1.34, sd] n^(-1/5)]`. Note also that `Quantile[data, .75] - Quantile[data, .25]` is quite different from `InterquartileRange[data]`, due to different defaults of `Quartile[]` and `Quantile[]` (also discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6892)).

Comment: The quantile calculation is not the point here. The point is: where does the 0.9 come from?

Comment: I'm correcting your formula after "*Mathematica* seems to use this result...", that's all. I don't know why that constant was chosen.

Comment: No problem - changed from `InterquartileRange` to `Quantile[data,.75] - Quantile[data,.25]`. All outputs remain the same either way.

Comment: That's probably due to the standard deviation being chosen by `Min[]` for your particular data set.

Comment: thanks ...am very pleased my guess is now spot on with the actual code _Mathematica_ uses ... especially the 0.9 part. Which leaves the question: why does _Mathematica_ use 0.9 to calculate Silverman's rule of thumb, rather than the theoretical value of approx 1.06?

Comment: @J.M. The rule of thumb used comes from page 48 of Silverman's own book "Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis" and is suggested as an improvement to 1.06 when considering a broader family of underlying distributions.

Comment: Thanks @Andy! For me, the problem in reproducing the results comes when using these distributions on multivariate data. Apparently, it's not as simple as applying the Silverman bandwidth estimate componentwise and making a diagonal matrix out of that, since there seems to be an extra factor multiplying this diagonal matrix. Would you happen to know what that factor is?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the edits. However, your change to the gaussian kernel has 2 problems. The first is that it is not the Gaussian kernel; the second is that your change causes the input further down:  `Bandwidth[data, gauss, Method -> Silverman]` to cease working or make sense, as you have now removed the defn for `gauss`.

Comment: Whoops, forgot the normalization. Anyway, this should be okay now.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks. P.S. I tried to email you regarding refereeing a paper ... not sure if you received it (or if my email ended up in junk mail) ...?

Comment: Haven't checked my e-mail lately. I'll send a reply later.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I think I found it--or, at least, I found a formula "close enough" to the way *Mathematica* calculates the BW by default:

```
hi = ((4*Subscript[σ, i]^5)/(3*n))^(1/5)
```

where `σ` is the standard deviation of the data. This should be performed to each component (e.g. i, j, k) of the dimensions.

The reference came from the folowing link:

http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/ebooks/html/spm/spmhtmlnode15.html

I still need to figure out: is there a way to actualy **see** what *Mathematica* has calculated for the BW?

Comment: I had classes with Prof. Härdle... his e-book is really amazing...

Comment: can you please put a link to these books?

Comment: You can get the bandwidth that was used using the undocumented property `"Bandwidth"` via `SmoothKernelDistribution["Bandwidth"]`

Comment: I'm not sure if his e-books are still available... but the R- and Matlab-codes use in e-books and classes are available at [this link](http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/quantnet/).

Comment: Härdle's notes for the xplore package are live ... interestingly, he also uses the 1.06 result (rather than the 0.9 version) ... http://sfb649.wiwi.hu-berlin.de/fedc_homepage/xplore/ebooks/html/spm/spmhtmlnode15.html