# Recreating SmoothDensityHistogram and SmoothKernelDistribution in another programming language

Tags: plotting, histograms

For the purpose of a research project I need to recreate results of some numeric simulation that was done in Wolfram Mathematica (I'm writing it in Python), regardless of the details, there is a contour plot that is written as

```
SmoothDensityHistogram[#, Mesh -> 5, MeshShading -> {None, None}]
```

Which gets 101 2D points. Trying to recreate the results, I looked up the function and saw that it calls SmoothKernelDistribution, since no particular options are specified, I assume it uses the default Silverman bandwidth selection, however, when trying to do the same thing in python I was not really able to recreate the results. For one, I see that Mathematica has a threshold for which some points that are far enough away from the largest congregations of points (so I guess a few sigmas away from the mean) are unaccounted for (in Python it's referred to as a threshold), and also I believe that there might be some other parameters I'm unaware of that are different. I also saw that Mathematica implements Silverman bandwidth differently than other tools.

I'm not very experienced in Mathematica or KDE functions, so I might be missing something trivial here. What are the default parameters for such a function? or how might I find them out?

Comment: I'm not sure that you've asked a question about the use of *Mathematica*.  Your comment about some points being unaccounted for should have a specific example.  Possibly it is when you `Plot` the curve when the displayed range is not adequate.  That can be fixed with changing the `PlotRange` option.  But it's hard to say without specifics.

Comment: I'm interested in knowing the default parameters of ```SmoothDensityHistogram``` and ```SmoothKernelDistribution```. Is there another stack exchange for such questions?

Comment: You might find all of the answers here:  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25423/the-default-bandwidth-of-the-smoothkerneldistribution-function.

Comment: I've read that article but didn't seem to find what I was looking for, I'll try looking at it again, perhaps I was missing out on some information.

Comment: Doesn't the explanation in that link about *Mathematica* using 0.9 rather than 1.06 as the multiplicative constant for Silverman's method clear things up?  The only other possibility I can think of is whether you used $n$ or $n-1$ when calculating the standard deviation.

Comment: I think that there is also some thresholding done in Mathematica, I see that not all points are within the contour by default. When using Silverman in Python for example, all points are included within the contour plot unless I specify some threshold.