# A summary command for statistics

Tags: probability-or-statistics

In R I can do:

```
summary(data)
```

Which gives  the min, max, median, first, and third quartiles. Is there a similar single command in Mathematica for this?

I know I can do:

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 100]
Table[f[data], {f, {Min, Quantile[#, .25] &, Median, 
   Quantile[#, .75] &, Max}}]
```

But wondering if there is a single command for this.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: @StefanR -  Actually, since `Quantile` accepts a list of quantiles:  `Quantile[data, Range[0, 1, .25]]`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even if there wasn't one, there is one now: I think you've just written it yourself :-)

```
summary[dset_] := Through[{Min, Quantile[#, .25] &, Median, Quantile[#, .75] &, Max}[dset]]

SeedRandom[1234]
data = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 100];
summary[data]

(* Out: {0, 18, 91/2, 66, 98} *)
```

Comment: Addendum: there might be a situation where one might need to fiddle with the third argument of `Quantile[]`. See e.g. [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6893).

Comment: @J.M. ah! Interesting, thank you for pointing it out. I'm delighted to see that you're back!

Answer (score 14):

On 2019-10-02 the resource function ["RecordsSummary"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RecordsSummary) was published at the [Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/).

Here is usage example (from the [resource function page](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/RecordsSummary)):

```
Block[{n = 200}, 
  arr = Flatten /@ 
    Transpose[{RandomReal[{-10, 10}, {n, 2}], 
      MapAt[ToLowerCase, 
       RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], {n, 2}], {All, 2}], 
      RandomChoice[{E, I, \[CapitalGamma]}, n]}]];

ResourceFunction["RecordsSummary"][arr]
```

[image]

### First answer (2016-02-25)

Some time ago I programmed such a function, `RecordsSummary`, inspired by R's `summary`. Here is an example of its usage: [Census data summary](https://mathematicaforprediction.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/adult-census-income-data-summary.png) .

As the name implies, it is assumed that we have a list of records, all with the same length, and we want the columns to be summarized. (Each record is a row.)

You can get the package [MathematicaForPredictionUtilities.m](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MathematicaForPredictionUtilities.m) from [MathematicaForPrediction at GitHub](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction) or simply run this command:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MathematicaForPredictionUtilities.m"]
```

Let us create random data.

```
data = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, 100];
dataCat = RandomChoice[Characters["azbuka"], 100];
data2 = RandomInteger[{0, 100}, {100, 4}];
```

Here are examples of using RecordsSummary over the created data.

**1.** Call on a 1D array:

```
RecordsSummary[ data ]
```

**2.** Summary of a 2D numeric array. The columns are named automatically.

```
RecordsSummary[N[data2]]
```

[image: RecordsSummary output for 2D numerical array]

**3.** Fancy output of numerical and categorical data summary. The column names are the second argument given to RecordsSummary.

```
Grid[{RecordsSummary[
   Transpose[{N[data], dataCat}], {"Numeric", "Categorical"}]}, 
 Alignment -> Top, Dividers -> All]
```

[image: RecordsSummary output for numerical and categorical data]

Comment: Can we have Recordsummary with respective to two variables that is, a response variable that is categorical and a predictor variable that is numeric?

Comment: @Srajan I am not sure what do you meant. The answer is "yes" to both interpretations I can come up with. **1.** If you have two columns, a categorical and a numerical one, then see the last example in this answer. **2.** If you mean an association of number-symbol pairs, then you can use `ResourceFunction["RecordsSummary"][asc, Thread -> True]`.