# Is it possible to user-define the percentages for lower/upper whisper/fence in BoxWhiskerChart of MMA?

Tags: plotting, graphics, probability-or-statistics

[BoxWhiskerChart](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoxWhiskerChart.html) draws a box-and-whisker summary of the distribution of the input data.

[image: mma-boxwhisker]

I would like to show the 2nd, 25th, 50th (the median), 75th, and 98th percentages of the input data.

> Is it possible to user-define the percentages for lower/upper whisper/fence in BoxWhiskerChart?

---

```
data = Table[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[5], 1], 100], {2}];
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers"]
```

Comment: You want the 2% and 98% to replace the min and max? or to show in addition to them?

Comment: [A related question.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6892)

Comment: @JasonB To replace the min and max. Thanks for your answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Brett's answer, we can do it like this

```
BoxWhiskerChart[data, 
  Method -> {"BoxRange" -> (Quantile[#, {2/100, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 
         98/100}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] &)}] /. {"min" -> "2%", 
  "max" -> "98%"}
```

[image]

### Problem with Outliers

For some reason changing the "BoxRange" method has the effect of removing some, but not always all, of the plotted outliers,

```
data = RandomVariate[
   NormalDistribution[RandomInteger[5], 1], {5, 100}];
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers"]
BoxWhiskerChart[data, "Outliers", 
  Method -> {"BoxRange" -> (Quantile[#, {2/100, 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 
         98/100}, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1}}] &)}] /. {"min" -> "2%", 
  "max" -> "98%"}
```

[image]

This seems odd to me, because the definition of an outlier from [this page](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/boxwhisk3.htm) would lead me to believe that a data point is an outlier if it is more than 1.5 times the interquartile range (the difference between the 75% and 25% values) lower than the 25% value.  Since we didn't change those levels I would naively think the definition of an outlier should remain constant.

Comment: How do you put two bar plots in one figure? - - I reproduce two BoxWhiskerPlots in my System but cannot get them to the same plot.